# i think promblem in version of my visual studio, some operator have change, because code i copy from book 2016

Tags: c, char, printf, scanf, c-strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 #define SIZE 20

 
 int main(void)
 {
     char string1[SIZE];
    
     char string2[] = "string literal"; 
    
     size_t i; 
    
         
     printf("%s", "Enter a string (no longer than 19 characters): ");\\problem there
    
     scanf_s("%19s", string1); \\problem there
     
     printf("string1 is: %s\n",string1)
     
     printf("string2 is: %s\n","string1 with spaces between characters is:\n", string2);

  for (i = 0; i < SIZE && string1[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
     printf("%c ", string1[i]);
     }
```

puts("");
}

\ i think promblem in version of my visual studio, some operator have change, because code i copy from book 2016

Comment: Which operator do think has changed? Why do you think that?

Comment: @Ksenia You need to write scanf_s("%19s", string1, ( rsize_t )20 ); instead of scanf_s("%19s", string1);

Comment: @Ksenia And in this call printf("string2 is: %s\n","string1 with spaces between characters is:\n", string2); the argument string2 is not used

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. It tells you what is wrong with `scanf_s("%19s", string1); \\problem there`. Note that the chance you found a bug in VS is vanishingly small.

Comment: "string1 with spaces between characters". The `scanf` function family has never been able to enter a string containing spaces with `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

The call of `scanf_s` with the conversion specifier `s` requires one more argument. That is instead of

```
scanf_s("%19s", string1); \\problem there
```

you need to write

```
scanf_s("%19s", string1, ( rsize_t )20 );
```

From the C Standard (K.3.5.3.2 The fscanf_s function). The quote is valid for the function `scanf_s`.

> 4 The fscanf_s function is equivalent to fscanf except that the c, s,
> and [ conversion specifiers apply to a pair of arguments (unless
> assignment suppression is indicated by a *). **The first of these
> arguments is the same as for fscanf. That argument is immediately
> followed in the argument list by the second argument, which has type
> rsize_t and gives the number of elements in the array pointed to by
> the first argument of the pair.** If the first argument points to a
> scalar object, it is considered to be an array of one element.

Though it would be better to write (if you allow the user to enter embedded spaces in the string)

```
scanf("%19[^\n]", string1);
```

or simply

```
scanf("%19s", string1);
```

In this call of `printf`

```
printf("string2 is: %s\n","string1 with spaces between characters is:\n", string2);
```

there is only one conversion specifier `s` but two arguments. The argument `string2` is not used.

It seems you mean the following

```
printf("string2 is: %s\n", string2);
printf( "string1 with spaces between characters is:\n" );
```

In the condition of this for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE && string1[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
```

the expression `i < SIZE` is redundant.